# Regular expression to replace Multi lookup values in sharepoint (ID;#) with a blank value

Tags: regex, vba, sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report that displays multi lookup values as

`1;#Entry 1;2;#Entry 2;3;#Entr 3;4;#Entries;5;#Pens;6;#8 Flipcharts;7;#22 TVs` etc .

I want to display the values as

`Entry 1;Entry2;Entry3;Entries;Pens;8 Flipcharts;22 TVs` .

I tried the below code , but the code replaces the numbers in the value side with blank.

```
Function ScrubText(ByVal value As String) As String 
   Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(value,";#\d*;#", "; ").Trim() 
End Function
```

How to modify regular expression in the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so now you should be replacing in steps
first do this

```
";d;" with ";"
```

then replace

```
"#" with ""
```

this should do the trick.

Comment: This gives the output as `;Entry ;;Entry ;;Entry 3`

Comment: @Ishan you changed the replacement string too?

Comment: replace your line with this line `Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(value,"\d*;#","").Trim()`

Comment: No it dint also to add to it i have values as `ID;#4 Flipcharts`